# Bash 'read' command hangs when executed from Putty or plink

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, putty

I'm trying to execute local bash script on a remote debian server from a Windows machine using putty. The script is very simple:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome."
read -p "Enter your name: " NAME
echo "Nice to see you, ${NAME}!"
```

The script works fine when executed from the debian server directly.

I installed Putty (version 0.73) to be able to execute it remotely by running the following cmd script:

```bsh
@ECHO OFF
start /b putty -ssh -m "hello.sh" "server.example.com"
```

I also tried using plink:

```bsh
@ECHO OFF
start /b plink -ssh -m "hello.sh" "server.example.com"
```

Both methods give the same result: the script hangs on the `read` instruction and nothing I type seems to alter the shell (even `enter` or `ctrl-c`). The prompt is not even displayed (but the "Welcome." message is echoed). The only thing I can do is kill the terminal by closing it.

Any idea what's causing this issue, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your are not in `terminal`  mode . *PUTTY* are waiting for the full line before display it .

You must run *PUTTY* with the option `-t`

[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)